# Mark properties of class for reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

Hi i got this simple DTO Class

```
public class Clientes_mdl
{        
    public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }        

    public Enumerador_mdl CondicionIva { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Enumerador_mdl> Transporte { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Direcciones_view> Direcciones { get; set; }
}
```

**ID_Cliente** and **RazonSocial** a data properties. **Transporte** and **Direcciones** are navigation properties to other classes.

And I use this reflection code, to get class properties names:

```
protected void base_UpdateCommand(IDbCommand myCommand, TEntity entity, string sWhere)
{
    var properties = (typeof(TEntity)).GetProperties().ToList();

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        if (prop.Name.ToUpper() != sKeyField.ToUpper()
        {
            sProps = sProps + prop.Name + "=@" + prop.Name + ", ";                    
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need a way to ignore navigation properties, and get only data properties names of the class (ID_Cliente and RazonSocial). Is there any decorators I can use to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Define your own "NavigationPropertyAttribute" class or find something already defined by .NET that makes sense use it to mark those properties.

Comment: Or follow a convention that properties of certain types are "data properties".

Comment: Thanks @Marker, thats what I was thinking. But how can I detect this Attribute in my reflection code?

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, that was my second choice, but how can I detect this "data properties" int my reflection code?

Comment: `propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes()`...

Comment: I haven't done it in a while, mostly Qt on Linux these days.  A quick search looks like each PropertyInfo has an Attributes collection.

Comment: You can get some great ideas on how this can be done by looking at the Dapper project: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L596

Comment: I also thought maybe you could define SomeNameData and SomeNameNavigation interfaces that you implement in you class an use the specific interface in reflection though I'm not sure if that will "separate/group" the properties.

Answer (score 1):

you could check if it is a class something like:

```
        var properties = typeof(Clientes_mdl).GetProperties();

        var propertyNames = properties
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string) ||
                        !x.PropertyType.IsClass ||
                        !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType)
            )
            .Select(x=>$"{x.Name} =@ {x.Name}")
            .ToArray();

        var propertyNameString = string.Join(",", propertyNames);
```

and if you wanted to leave the lists in there you could remove `!typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType)`

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks to your suggestions:

```
public class Clientes_mdl
{        
    public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }        

    [KeyAttribute]
    public Enumerador_mdl CondicionIva { get; set; }
    [KeyAttribute]
    public Nullable<Enumerador_mdl> Transporte { get; set; }
    [KeyAttribute]
    public IEnumerable<Direcciones_view> Direcciones { get; set; }
}
```

And the reflection code:

```
protected void base_UpdateCommand(IDbCommand myCommand, TEntity entity, string sWhere)
{
    var properties = (typeof(TEntity)).GetProperties().ToList();

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        bool bIgnore = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a is KeyAttribute);
        if (prop.Name.ToUpper() != sKeyField.ToUpper() && !bIgnore)
        {
            sProps = sProps + prop.Name + "=@" + prop.Name + ", ";                    
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you doing this every time you call `base_UpdateCommand` or is this just a pseudo code? How many times do you call `base_UpdateCommand`? if you call it many times you will suffer from performance with this implementation a lot

Comment: Thanks @EmrahSüngü. Yes I know that using reflection has an impact on perfomance. I use this funcion to create an SQL Command to update a database object based on object properties. Kind of like EF do. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Yeah sure you can reduce the reflection call to only once during the lifecycle of the application by using a concurrent dictionary. Based on the number of times you call this method you will get significant performance boost. Lemme know if you can't think of implementation